# How to convert a multi-key dictionary to a pandas dataframe, where each key and value has its own column?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
mkd = {('aab', 'ccd', 'bbd'): 3, ('aeb', 'cfd', 'bfd'): 8, ('atb', 'cttd', 'bft'): 83}
```

How could I mad a pandas dataframe where each key and value has its own column.

I see there's a solution for creating a pandas df from here

[Creating a panda DataFrame from dictionary with multiple keys and value (list) of different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837752/creating-a-panda-dataframe-from-dictionary-with-multiple-keys-and-value-list-o)

```
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems()]))
```

But the solution results in a muli-header

```
aab
ccd
bbd
3
```

Where as I am looking for an example row of this

```
        col1  col2  col3 col4
    0 'aab' 'ccd'  'bbd'     3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert it to a series and then reset index:

```
pd.Series(mkd).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  level_0 level_1 level_2   0
0     aab     ccd     bbd   3
1     aeb     cfd     bfd   8
2     atb    cttd     bft  83
```